# Flex mobile prevent item renderer state from recycled

Tags: list, apache-flex, mobile, itemrenderer, states

I have this custom list item renderer where I have defined 2 custom states:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="expand"/>
    <s:State name="collapse"/>
</s:states>
```

When I select one of the list item, it will change to state collapse. Now whenever I select the first or the last item in the list and I refresh the data provider, the current state of both the items will swap places.

Please guide me on how to retain the state of the itemrenderer. Thank you.

Note: It all works well when I change the usevirtuallayout to false. But, it is not what I intended to change.

**[Edit]
The following is my code for the item renderer:**

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

protected function init(event):void
{
    currentState = "collapse";
}

override public function set data(value:Object):void 
{
    trace(currentState.toString());
}

protected function btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    currentState = "expand";
}

]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="expand"/>
    <s:State name="collapse"/>
</s:states>

<s:Button id="changeStateButton" click="btn_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

The example above is a simple item renderer where a single button will change the currentState of the itemrenderer. I have 3 items in the data provider and each one of them is in the "collapse" state by default. This is the trace result from the set data function:

```
collapse
collapse
collapse
```

When I click the button at the last item... this will be the trace result:

```
collapse
collapse
expand
```

Now, when I refresh the data provider by calling this function "arraycollection.refresh()"...this is the result:

```
expand
collapse
collapse
```

Can somebody explain this scenario? Notice that this only happens when the `useVirtualLayout` is set to true...

Comment: Please give more context. The code used to display the list by example.

Comment: hi @PascalLeMerrer please refer to the new edit I added above

Answer (score 0):

Try reassigning the item renderer after updating the data provider.

```
//update data provider
itemList.dataProvider = myCollection;
//update the item renderer
itemList.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(cutomItemRenderer);
```

This solution of course will be more resource intensive.